# Style guide on writing long Python code lines

Tags: python, python-2.x

When building a working example of a class, I ended up with the following statements which is violating the 80 character rule of PEP8. The code was inside a method inside a class.

Code excerpt is from `PrettyTable.__init__()` and `PrettyTable.add_column()` in [my answer](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106184/78136) to [Using changeable column formatting to display table](//codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106156/using-changeable-column-formatting-to-display-table). Have however left out some of the surrounding code to make it easier to get better reviews:

```
class SomeClass():
    def some_method(self):
        if self._replace_space_char == None:
            self._replaced_column_separator = self._column_separator
        else:
            self._replaced_column_separator = self._column_separator.replace(' ', self._replace_space_char)

        self._header_text.append(self.HEADER_PART.format(title, header_alignment, width, self._replaced_column_separator))
```

Do you have any suggestion as to how to make this readable, and still maintain good variable names and legal Python code? I'm especially interested in how to fold/wrap/... when the construct `self._variable_name.some_method()` is by it self in excess of 30-50 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get here solely from reading PEP8. Also, don't use `==` to compare with singletons like `None`, [use `is` instead](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

```
class SomeClass():
    def some_method(self):
        if self._replace_space_char is None:
            self._replaced_column_separator = self._column_separator
        else:
            self._replaced_column_separator = self._column_separator.replace(
              ' ', self._replace_space_char,
              )

        self._header_text.append(
          self.HEADER_PART.format(
            title, header_alignment, width, 
            self._replaced_column_separator,
          )
        )
```

From [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id12):

> The 4-space rule is optional for continuation lines.
>
> Optional:
>
> ```
> # Hanging indents *may* be indented to other than 4 spaces.
> foo = long_function_name(
>   var_one, var_two,
>   var_three, var_four)
> ```

This allows obviously nested arguments to be differentiated from code blocks.

Not in PEP8, I like to end arguments with a comma so that insertion of new arguments in version control only affect a single line. Imagine the following was in a diff from version control, and note the single additional line, and no removed lines:

```
          self.HEADER_PART.format(
            title, header_alignment, width, 
            self._replaced_column_separator,
+           new_arg,
          )
```

Python ignores the ending comma.

More thoughts when looking at this code: To improve readability, consider changing to keyword arguments, especially if you have sensible defaults. You can go to one line per argument as well.

Comment: It looses a little on readability, but then again that is the major part of this question how not to loose readability...

Comment: Just to note you are allowed 'Aligned with opening delimiter' indents, as well.

Comment: Will the extra comma affect number of elements if using something like `my_func(*args)`? Or wil it be stripped away before the function is called?

Comment: Python ignores the ending comma.